# Quarkus Kubernetes Client - TimeoutException

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, smallrye, fabric8-kubernetes-client

We have upgraded Quarkus from 2.11.1 to 3.6.6. In earlier version 2.11.1. Kubernetes Client worked smoothly, but on version 3.6.6 Kubernetes client gave Timeout exception.

Exception details - (vert.x-worker-thread-10) Exception thrown during asynchronous load: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.

When we add @Blocking(io.smallrye.common.annotation) Annotation on method then it works. But here making this blocking behavior is not a good practice.

*Complete exception.*

```
(vert.x-worker-thread-10) Exception thrown during asynchronous load: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:509)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:524)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:467)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:791)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.requireFromServer(BaseOperation.java:192)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:148)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:97)
        at com.rockwell.idp.security.identity.cache.IdentityProviderCache.getConfigMap(IdentityProviderCache.java:112)
        at com.rockwell.idp.security.identity.cache.IdentityProviderCache.lambda$getIdentityProviderDetailsByTenantId$0(IdentityProviderCache.java:103)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:35)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.DelegatingHandler.handle(DelegatingHandler.java:25)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.WorkerContext.execute(WorkerContext.java:111)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.WorkerContext.execute(WorkerContext.java:53)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.WorkerContext.execute(WorkerContext.java:65)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:184)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:51)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
        at io.vertx.core.Promise.complete(Promise.java:66)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.ReplyHandler.dispatch(ReplyHandler.java:97)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration$InboundDeliveryContext.execute(HandlerRegistration.java:137)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.DeliveryContextBase.next(DeliveryContextBase.java:80)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.DeliveryContextBase.dispatch(DeliveryContextBase.java:43)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.dispatch(HandlerRegistration.java:98)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.ReplyHandler.doReceive(ReplyHandler.java:81)
        at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.HandlerRegistration.lambda$receive$0(HandlerRegistration.java:49)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.WorkerContext.lambda$null$1(WorkerContext.java:92)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.AsyncUtils.lambda$withTimeout$0(AsyncUtils.java:42)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.lambda$schedule$6(Utils.java:473)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        ... 1 more
```

Expecting to work without using @Blocking annotation

Answer (score 0):

> When we add `@Blocking` (io.smallrye.common.annotation) Annotation on method then it works.

Yes, this is the workaround that will prevent these types of issues from popping up in the more strict Quarkus 3.x version (regarding Vert.x reactive code).

> But here making this blocking behavior is not a good practice.

It would be good to see the code that triggers the exception to understand better.

Currently, all of the KubernetesClient calls are blocking.
The client performs calls to the Kube API server in a synchronous fashion.
You need to either use the `@Blocking` annotation to make the complete logic of that method blocking or move the KubernetesClient related logic somewhere else so that it's processed asynchronously.

You can check the Repo's issue for more information https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38133

Comment: Just to give glimpse of code.

`return io.vertx.mutiny.core.eventbus.EventBus.<JsonObject>request("address_to_send", data)
 .map(Message::body)
 .onItem().transform(json -> {
 //.. some if else checks
 return getConfigMap("configmapname"));
});
  
private JsonObject getConfigMap(String configMap) {
 Map<String, String> map = io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient.configMaps().inNamespace("namespace_name").withName(configMap).get().getData();
 //The above throws Timeout execption
}`

Comment: I understand, the problem is that kubernetesClient.configMaps()....get() is blocking, it might take from a few milliseconds to multiple seconds to complete. So it's not OK to use it in code that's supposed to be non-blocking. You need to refactor that code, or use one of the blocking wrappers provided. Either the annotation, or https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Context.html#executeBlocking-java.util.concurrent.Callable-boolean-